# How to Perform Explicit Conversion in Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How to Perform Explicit Conversion in Dynamic Pivot.

I need to convert datatype for single field.

This is my sample query

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + (QUOTENAME(P.ColumnName))from #temp as p 
JOIN information_schema.columns as C ON P.ColumnName=C.column_name
where C.table_name='tablename'

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + 'from (select ColumnVlaue, ColumnName from #temp) x
              pivot(max(ColumnVlaue) for ColumnName in (' + @cols + ')) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Sigh. So which field needs to be converted, and from what to what? Look up the CONVERT and CAST keywords.

Comment: @simonatrcl I need to convert varchar to varbinary

Comment: I think Mikael has showed you the answer below.

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to implement it in my solution

Answer (score 1):

You do it when you build the `@cols` variable.

Actually you need a second `@cols` variable `@cols2` that holds the columns with the cast expression.

If `@cols` contains `Col1, Col2` then `@Cols2` should be  `cast(Col1 as int) as Col1, cast(Col2 as int) as Col2`

Use `@Cols2` in the select column list and `@Cols` in the pivot column list.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols2 + 'from (select ColumnVlaue, ColumnName from #temp) x
              pivot(max(ColumnVlaue) for ColumnName in (' + @cols + ')) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Hi thank for your reply. I don know how to implement your idea in my solution. I want to convert only one filed from Nvarchar to varbinary

Comment: I have temp table as CoulmnName and ColumnValue in temp table